# How to set tick length in y-axis to 0 or remove tickline from y axis in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

for x axis 'tickLength: 0' is working and I can remove the tick from x-axis label,but same thing not working for y axis. Please suggest me the right way to remove the y axis tick line.

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#C9F4F4']
});
$('.container').highcharts({        
    chart: {
        type: 'area',          
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on', 
        overflow:'false',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        //tickLength: 0,
        startOnTick:true,
        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {             
        min: 100, 
        max: 1000,
        tickInterval: 100,                           
        gridLineWidth: 1,               
        title: {
            enabled: false
        },
        labels: {                                
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true, 
        formatter: function () {
            return this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {                
            lineColor: '#00CFCF',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#00CFCF',
                enabled: false,                    
            }
        }
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 900, 1000, 1000,200,750,630,400,75]
    }]
});
```

});

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/xznu95mv/3/)

Comment: Have you tried to set tickWidth as 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the desired effect? http://jsfiddle.net/xznu95mv/5/

In xAxis part,
Change `startOnTick: true,` to `startOnTick: false,`
Add `min: 0.5`

Ref: [How to remove the gap between yAxis and data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194187/how-to-remove-the-gap-between-yaxis-and-data)

Comment: yes tick mark is removed but the original position of Jan,Feb,Mar,..etc has been moved to forward and not starting from zero co-ordinate. In short chart's x axis tick mark must not changed to diffrent position.

Comment: Updated. Is it the desired effect?